How does a website check DNS leaks?
There are a few websites to allow you to view your DNS. For example, a nice one is: https://browserleaks.com/dns.
How does this kind of website work? Especially, I have enabled DNS over HTTPS, but the website still shows my DNS provider correctly.

When you are using DNS over HTTPS (DoH), the only protected path is between your browser and the DoH server you are connecting to. The DoH server obviously knows your IP address, since your browser makes a direct HTTPS connection to it, and further more, it may send your IP address upstream to the authoritative DNS server for that domain e.g. using EDNS Client Subnet (RFC 7871]). Common use for this is for resolving based on the geolocation of the actual request instead of that of the caching dns server.
Of course, whether the original IP (or subnet) gets forwarded to the authoritative DNS server, depends on how the DoH server is configured, but looking e.g. at the Mozilla DOH Resolver Policy it seems to be common in the industry to have some restrictions (see point 6 of that policy, e.g. not send to upstream unencrypted), but leaves it acceptable in some situations.
In other words, if you want your IP to not propagate to the authoritative DNS server, you would need to find a DoH server that does not use RFC 7871 to propagate your IP. I am not aware of any, but also didn't do any detailed search for that specifically.
Edit After reading your message again, not sure exactly what you mean with

shows my DNS provider correctly

If this is your DoH DNS provider, that makes the whole process even simpler, because there does not need to be EDNS Client Subnet involved. I assumed here you instead mean your local resolver, basically your local public IP, which needs to involve RFC 7871 to work.
Update
I did some tests now locally, and checked the output of https://browserleaks.com/dns with 2 default DoH providers in Firefox and 5 default providers in Chrome. For all those, browserleaks was basically showing the provider I had selected and nothing indicating my local IP as the original source of the DNS resolution request. So while what I described above (leaking the originator IP with EDNS Client Subnet) is technically possible, it seems that either those default providers do that, or browserleaks does not interpret that information.
To understand what is happening in your case, it would help if you update your question with details of the results you are getting from browserleaks.com and how they are connected to "your DNS provider".


How does this kind of website work?

Your browser asks the local DNS server to resolve the hostname. The local DNS server then sends a DNS query to the authoritative DNS server. browserleaks.com controls the authoritative DNS server ("This test attempts to resolve 50 randomly generated domain names", and you can see that these domains are like r50q8om8uo71xkwz.dns4.browserleaks.org), so it can see the IP address in the DNS query sent from your local DNS server.

Especially, I have enabled DNS over HTTPS, but the website still shows my DNS provider correctly.

HTTPS (TLS) encrypts the application layer only, i.e. the HTTP (and DNS) messages, including the hostname of the domain in the DNS query and the IP address to the domain in the DNS response. But the IP address of the local DNS server is in the IP header, in the network layer. What's more, the encryption is only for man-in-the-middle, but browserleaks.com controls the server. Since it is not a man-in-the-middle, even the DNS messages are in plaintext for browserleaks.com.
